# Why was this flag to move this question to codereview declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

Why was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765745/can-someone-please-give-professional-and-critical-feedback-to-my-freecodecamp-ra) flag to move it to codereview declined?

I mean look at the title, *"can someone please give professional and critical feedback to my freecodecamp random quote generator"*.

If you read the question

> I have completed my random quote generator project and it will be nice
> to have feedback from you guys on my code and how it is structure and
> any other things that I suppose to have done,

`giant code dump follows the above text`

And every comment says the same thing that this belongs on codereview and have multiple upvotes each.

#### Why was this declined?

Comment: But is the only problem with it that it's just on the wrong site? if it's a crap question (which i can't see because it's been self deleted) it shouldn't be migrated, you don't migrate crap. wasn't that the complaint of Computer Science when they were Programmers and crap questions were being dumped on them?

Comment: is there a screenshot for those of us who cannot view the deleted question being asked about?

Comment: When was the flag declined? Before or after it was deleted?

Comment: The flag was declined after the post was deleted, which is presumably why. (Not the mod that handled it).

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters it is hard to tell when things get handled and what not.

Answer (score 9):

You can't just look at the title alone to decide if this question should go on Code Review, especially because titles can be misleading.

For context (and those who are < 10K rep), here's the question with the code omitted.

> I have completed my random quote generator project and it will be nice
>   to have feedback from you guys on my code and how it is structure and
>   any other things that I suppose to have done,  [here is the link to my
>   codepen][1]
>
> [1]: http://codepen.io/famousmighodaro/pen/BRdjQW/

A few issues arise [using Code Review's handy checklist](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users):

- **The question lacks context.**  Okay, they've got code which does a thing and they want feedback on that thing, but it's unclear what that thing *is*.
- **It's unclear if it works.**  This leans a bit more on context, but there's no indication if the code works to begin with.  Sure, the Codepen link *does* work, but most of the HTML isn't present in their original question.
- **The comments stating that this should go there *are* wrong.**  Just because someone thinks it should be on Code Review doesn't mean it should be on Code Review.  This will undoubtedly cause grief on the part of the OP for getting a poor referral when they're ill-equipped to handle it.

For extra credit...

- **The OP *themselves* deleted the question!**  I don't see value in migrating a deleted question anywhere.

Let's try not to migrate crap.  This looks pretty poor, and we don't want to send poor questions over there.

Comment: I declined that flag for pretty much the reasons described above. The fact that it was deleted didn't weigh as much on my decision, I just didn't think the question was of a high enough quality to be migrated. The question was poorly formatted and seemed to be way too broad to fit Code Review. Providing an entire project and asking for feedback on "structure and any other things that I suppose to have done" is demanding quite a lot from the people of Code Review. We decline a lot of requests to migrate to Code Review, because they don't appreciate if we migrate bad questions.