# Edit then move question to another site, or move then edit?

Tags: discussion, triage

Let's say I'm reviewing a question in triage and find both of these actions are needed:

- The question needs to be moved to another site
- The asker needs to revise the question to meet that other site's quality standards

Assuming these are correct, what's the right way to proceed?  Should I tell the asker to revise the question to meet the standards of [other SE site] before it's even been moved?  If I'm not on [other SE site], I'd have to tell the asker to revise the question according to [other SE site]'s standards before it's even moved, which seems weird...

Comment: I think you'd find out whether this is something [code review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/) would want?

Comment: Right, based on my read of the site, it looked like the question could be appropriate AFTER editing to meet quality standards.  But I didn't see a scenario where it made sense to leave it on SO, edited or otherwise.

Comment: My point is, you could always ask them. There's no point editing it if they say they don't want it come what may.

Comment: Gotcha.  I'll try that, though I'm also interested in the general case of this question.  I'll revise my question accordingly.

Comment: [You're wrong about this being suitable for Code Review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362417/1079354)

Comment: @Makoto Right, I've been reading up on [guidelines](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions) and rummaging through CR's meta to decide.  Though more importantly, I'm asking this question RE the general case of a question that needs 2 actions, one being a move.

Comment: [In general, the immediate instinct to migrate the question is incorrect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348819/1079354), ***99.99999%*** of the time.

Comment: @makoto That's fine, I didn't do it, but that's **still not my question**.

Comment: @TTT No, your question simply *assumes* that migration is appropriate.  You're being told that migration is *not* appropriate.  One of the assumptions you based your question on is wrong.  That's something worth Makoto pointing out to you.

Comment: @Servy In my last comment, "I didn't do it" = "I didn't recommend the question be migrated".  I instead went off to do my homework learning about CR, and simultaneously asked this general question.  The referenced question lacked any info when I reviewed, so there was no way to assess (hypothetical) post-revision quality.  But it seems to be garnering undue attention, so I'll remove all reference to it.

Comment: @TTT The problem is not that you linked the question, it's that you're *assuming a problematic question needs to be migrated*.  The problem is the line, "The question needs to be moved to another site", not in anything you just removed.  That is the invalid assumption you're making, and that's what Makoto has pointed out to you.

Comment: @Servy Let's continue in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195720/meta-chat-for-edit-then-move-question-to-another-site-or-move-then-edit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should migrate content that is not yet suitable for target site - the experience OP will get as result would be from confusing to painful (downvotes/close resulting in rejected migration leaving question in strange state).

If you are willing to edit the question yourself I'd recommend editing first and then flagging for migration. Doing migration the other way would drop low quality question on the target site at an arbitrary moment in time and you may not be able to edit the question there in timely manner (I assume you have at least editing privileges on target site as you are confident in what is actually "good question" there).

Otherwise close the question on the source site, then advice OP to read guidance for target site and create a new question there. If interested consider guiding OP via comments, chat and off-site resources to craft good question for target site.

---

<sub>Note: if you don't have some decent reputation/privileges on target site it is *very likely* you are wrong about whether question fits there or not - this post is strictly about what can be done when you *know from experience* that the question is good fit on target site but requires relatively minor edits first.</sub>